# Visual Studio 2012 - Values in debug watch are not displayed when compiled with /clr

Tags: visual-studio-2012, clr, visual-studio-debugging

The debug watch doesn't display values for objects like std::vector for example.
On the other hand, values of local integers are displayed.

When I compile the project without `/clr` option everything is displayed correct.

I tried different DebugModes (Mixed, Auto, Managed...) and played around with different settings just like JIT, "Enable .Net Framework source stepping" and Symbol server. But the problem remained. (After each change of the settings the project was clean/build again)

```
//#pragma managed(push, off)
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int a = 5; //displayed correctly in debug watch
    vector<myInt> vec;
    myInt X(4);
    vec.push_back(X); // displayed as Name: "vec", Value: "{...}" (no option to expand it)
    vec.push_back(X+X);
    vec.push_back(std::move(X));

    std::vector<int> vec2;
    vec2.push_back(a);



    return 0;
}

//#pragma managed(pop)
```

Comment: The many mysteries of main...  The entrypoint of a managed program is `void Main(array<String^>^ args)`.  One argument, not two.  Use it properly and the debugger stops getting confused about what the stack frame looks like.